Finding if strings can be anagrams
I have String s1 and String s2. I want to check whether it is possible to make s1 an anagram of s2 by removing a single character zero or more times from s1, and removing a single character zero or more times from s2.
Examples
Example 1:
s1 = "safddadfs"
s2 = "famafmss"

Result = true

Explanation:

s1 has 2 x 'a', 2 x 'd', 2 x 'f', 2 x 's'
s2 has 2 x 'a', 2 x 'm', 2 x 'f', 2 x 's'

We can remove 'd' from s1 and remove 'm' from s2 to make them anagrams: both s1 and s2 become 2 x 'a', 2 x 'f', 2 x 's'
Example 2:
s1 = "aaabb"
s2 = "aabbb"

Result = true

Explanation:

s1 has 3 x 'a', 2 x 'b'
s2 has 2 x 'a', 3 x 'b'

We can remove a single 'a' from s1 and a single 'b' from s2 to make them anagrams: both become 2 x 'a', 2 x 'b'.
Example 3:
s1 = "aab"
s2 = "ab"

Result = true

Explanation:

s1 has 2 x 'a', 1 x 'b'
s2 has 1 x 'a', 1 x 'b'

We can remove a single 'a' from s1 and nothing from s2 to make them anagrams: both become 1 x 'a', 1 x 'b'.
Attempt
I tried implementing the code for this, as follows:
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static boolean solve(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, Integer> m1 = getCountMap(s1);
        Map<Character, Integer> m2 = getCountMap(s2);
        boolean valid = canBeAnagrams(m1, m2);
        
        if(!valid) {
            valid = canBeAnagrams(m2, m1);
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private static boolean canBeAnagrams(Map<Character, Integer> m3, Map<Character, Integer> m4) {
        int count = 0;
        Map<Character, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>(m3), m2 = new HashMap<>(m4);
        for(char c : m1.keySet()) {
            int v1 = m1.get(c);
            int v2 = m2.getOrDefault(c,0);
            if(v1 != v2) {
                count++;
            }
            m2.remove(c);
            if(count > 1) return false;
        }   
        if(m2.size() > 1) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static Map<Character, Integer> getCountMap(String s) {
        Map<Character, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            countMap.put(c, countMap.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
        }
        return countMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve("safddadfs", "famafmss"));  // Should print true
        System.out.println(solve("aaabb", "aabbb"));  // Should print true, but getting false
        System.out.println(solve("aab", "ab"));  // Should print true
    }
}

Problem
My code is failing for the test case where s1 = "aaabb" and s2 = "aabb".
Where is my mistake in the logic and how to fix this?

One way to make life easier and the standard way to key anagrams is to sort the letters of the two words into alphabetical order before you start. Then it is much easier to see and to program the logic to find the difference(s).

@trincot removing a single character (any number of times) from each string s1 and s2 so s1 = a:3, b:2 and s2 = a:2,b:3 , so I will remove single a from s1 and single b from s2 to make them anagram

Alright, so you don't have to remove all occurrences from them. I see.

@JerryCoffin, it was typo error, I corrected it now

There are two issues:

When v1 != v2 there is only one of the strings that needs to delete the relevant character (one or more times) to make both strings equal with respect to that character, but as you potentially call canBeAnagrams twice, you will then count this change twice, once for each string. This comparison should be v1 > v2 to correct this.

The calling code has if(!valid) as condition to make the second call. But this means that if the first call returns false, there is still chance the final result would be true. This is not correct. If one call returns false, then that's it. On the other hand, when you get true from the first call, you still could get false from the opposite check, so the second call should then be made. In short, this if should be if (valid).


With these two issues fixed it should work.
Improvements
You could however do this with fewer traversals and without calls to remove. Consider the differences in counts per letter. You'd allow for one difference to be negative and one difference to be positive, not more. So you could mutate the map created for the second string by subtracting the counts collected in the first map, and then see if that condition is true:
    public static boolean solve(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, Integer> m1 = getCountMap(s1);
        Map<Character, Integer> diff = getCountMap(s2);
        boolean occurred[] = { false, false };
        for (char c : m1.keySet()) {
            diff.put(c, diff.getOrDefault(c, 0) - m1.get(c));
        }
        for (char c : diff.keySet()) {
            int delta = diff.get(c);
            if (delta == 0) continue;
            int side = delta > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            if (occurred[side]) return false;
            occurred[side] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }


The improved code looks nice. :-)

I would do this a little differently. I'd count up the characters in the first string, about like you are now, but for the second string, I'd count downward (in the same map).
When you're done, you can create an anagram if you have no more than 2 non-zero values, only one of which can be positive and one negative.
In C++ (sorry, I don't do Java much), it would look a bit like this:
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

bool solve(std::string const &s1, std::string const &s2) { 
    std::map<char, int> counts;

    for (auto const c : s1)
        ++counts[c];

    for (auto const &c : s2)
        --counts[c];

    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;

    for (auto [_, count] : counts) {
        if (count > 0) ++pos;
        else if (count < 0) ++neg;
    }

    return pos <= 1 && neg <= 1;
}

int main() { 
    using TestType = std::tuple<std::string, std::string, bool>;
    using std::get;
    
    std::vector<TestType> tests {
        { "safddadfs", "famafmss", true},
        { "aaabb", "aabbb", true},
        { "aab", "ab", true},
        { "abc", "abcde", false},
    };

    for (auto const &test : tests) {
        assert(solve(get<0>(test), get<1>(test)) == get<2>(test));
    }
}

